# Create multiple arrays with names consisting of both a letter and a number in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, numbers, character

I want to create 10 1D arrays with names consisting of
both a letter, say A, and a number in C. And then, by using loops, I want to assign values to these arrays. For instance:

`for(j=1; j<=10; j++){for(i=0; i<10; i++){A'j'[i]=i+1;}}`

How can i accomplish this?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: "I want to" means "My homework assignment is to", right?  But I'd say you *don't* want to do this.  If you want to use a loop, then you want to use an array (or, in this case, an array of arrays), so that you can straightforwardly do something like `array[j][i]`.  You can't construct variable names on the fly, with constants like `'A'`, like you're trying to.

Comment: No you cannot. The names of variables are gone when you run your program. What is your real task? Can't you use a 2D array, or a 1D array of 1D arrays?

Comment: Variable names exists solely for the benefit of the programmer. Not for the user and not for the final executable. Therefore, generating variable names in run-time is nonsense - that's not how programming works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone. the busybee, alright How can I use/allocate a 1D array of 1D arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to create loops with the precompiler, so one idea solving your issue would be by using an array of pointers to access the ten 1D arrays. The solution would be better however by using a 2D array.

```
#define OUTER_ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define INNER_ARRAY_SIZE 5

int main (void)
{
    /* Define ten 1D arrays with naming scheme <character><number> */
    int a0[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], b1[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], c2[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], d3[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], e4[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], f5[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], g6[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], h7[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], i8[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE], j9[INNER_ARRAY_SIZE];

    /* Define 1D array of pointers */
    int* array[OUTER_ARRAY_SIZE];

    /* Initialize: */
    array[0] = &a0[0]; /* or array[0] = a0; */
    array[1] = &b1[0]; 
    array[2] = &c2[0]; 
    array[3] = &d3[0]; 
    array[4] = &e4[0]; 
    array[5] = &f5[0]; 
    array[6] = &g6[0]; 
    array[7] = &h7[0]; 
    array[8] = &i8[0]; 
    array[9] = &j9[0];

    for( int count = 0; count < OUTER_ARRAY_SIZE; count ++ )
    {
        for( int inner = 0; inner < INNER_ARRAY_SIZE; inner++)
        {
            *(array[count]+inner) = count + inner + 1;
        }
    }
    
    
    for( int count = 0; count < OUTER_ARRAY_SIZE; count ++)
    {
        for( int inner = 0; inner < INNER_ARRAY_SIZE; inner++)
        {
            printf("%2d,", *array[count]+inner);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```